# Replace all the relative path with absolute path and ignore the paths that is already absolute using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have the following string,

```
Some text ![test1](assets/image1.png) \n some text ![test2](https://example.com/assets/image2.png) some other text \n ![test3](assets/image3.png)
```

I want to replace all the relative image paths i.e. `assets/image1.png` to `https://example.com/assets/image1.png` and same for `assets/image3.png`. But we need to ignore `https://example.com/assets/image2.png` as it is already absolute path.

So far I have been able to do the following,

```js
const getImagesWithAbsolutePath = (text, absolutePathPrefix) => {
    if (!text) return ''
    const regex = /(\!\[.*\]\()(.*)(\))/g
    return text.replace(regex, '$1' + absolutePathPrefix + '/$2?raw=true$3')
}

myText = "Some text ![test1](assets/image1.png) \n some text ![test2](https://example.com/assets/image2.png) some other text \n ![test3](assets/image3.png)";

myDomain = "https://example.com";

console.log(getImagesWithAbsolutePath(myText, myDomain));
```

As you can see the output is,

```
 Some text ![test1](https://example.com/assets/image1.png?raw=true) 
 some text ![test2](https://example.com/https://example.com/assets/image2.png?raw=true) some other text 
 ![test3](https://example.com/assets/image3.png?raw=true)
```

But I need the result to be,

```
Some text ![test1](https://example.com/assets/image1.png?raw=true) 
some text ![test2](https://example.com/assets/image2.png?raw=true) some other text 
![test3](https://example.com/assets/image3.png?raw=true)
```

Comment: Use lazy dot (`/(\!\[.*?\]\()(.*?)(\))/g`), or negated character classes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, It doesn't work. Returns the same result.

Comment: Besides this question is not duplicate. I have seen that question and it doesn't actually help. Thanks.

Comment: Right, you need to match the host optionally.

Comment: Anyway, you really need to use lazy dot/negated character classes in the pattern to handle multiple matches on the same line. I was tricked at first because I did not spot all `\n` in your sample string literals. It is a good idea to also add the literal text you deal with to the question, but code is always good, too, sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

- Use lazy dot / negated character classes to make sure you do not match across your `(`/`)` and `[`/`]` delimiters
- Match the `myDomain` host part optionally, so that it could be removed when you add it back with the replacement:

```js
const myDomain = "https://example.com";
const getImagesWithAbsolutePath = (text, absolutePathPrefix) => {
    if (!text) return ''
    const regex =  new RegExp("(!\\[.*?]\\()(?:" + myDomain.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + "/*)?(.*?)(\\))", "g")
    return text.replace(regex, '$1' + absolutePathPrefix + '/$2?raw=true$3')
}

let myText = "Some text ![test1](assets/image1.png) \n some text ![test2](https://example.com/assets/image2.png) some other text \n ![test3](assets/image3.png)";

console.log(getImagesWithAbsolutePath(myText, myDomain));
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WPArGX/1).

*Details*:

- `(!\[.*?]\()` - Group 1: `!`, `[`, any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible, `](`
- `(?:https:\/\/example\.com\/*)?` - an optional occurrence of `https://example.com` string and then zero or more `/` chars
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(\))` - Group 3: `)` char.

NOTE: if you happen to have `$` + digit in the `absolutePathPrefix` (`myDomain`), you will need to replace with `'$1' + absolutePathPrefix.replace(/\$/g, '$$$$') + '/$2?raw=true$3'`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. At first, I was not sure how it was working. Your explanation helped a lot. Kudos!